# CocoaPods Build Errors

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am creating a new iOS project with CocoaPods but have been running into build errors.

```
PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomerApp-gicarwczuupvbxarirfljoeveuoc/Build/Intermediates/CustomerApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomerApp.build/Script-EBA9FF40759E4567A8222C4B.sh
cd /Users/.../Documents/CustomerApp
/bin/sh -c /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CustomerApp-gicarwczuupvbxarirfljoeveuoc/Build/Intermediates/CustomerApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomerApp.build/Script-EBA9FF40759E4567A8222C4B.sh

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2
```

I have checked

- PodsFile.lock and Manifest.lock and they are identical
- PodsFile.lock and Manifest.lock have -rw-r--r- permission
- PODS_ROOT has been set in xCode Build Settings
- Project Configuration has been set to Pods for both Debug and Release

I have also tried to recreate the test project, delete and refresh the PodFile and the Pod dir and no success.

(Obviously) If I remove the build phases related to CocoaPods the project then successfully builds :-s

xCode 5.1 CocoaPods 0.33.1

Comment: Are you opening the project `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj` ? If not, do so.

Comment: I am in the workspace :(